# Coreplot Y axis cut off / no numbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am having issues with my implementation of CorePlot. I have a subview in my UIViewController than contains the chart. Most of the data shows up fine but no increments / values are showing up on the y axis.

This is what I am seeing now:
[image]

If I shift the x axis start point by subtracting 10 (to better see the left half of the chart) I see this:
[image]

For the record, I do not have any values outside of the (positive x, positive y) quadrant on the chart and have logged out my data to verify this. Any input / advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

This guy does a great job explaining that about halfway down... search for "You're Getting There!" to find exactly where he talks about the weird lines in the Y axis.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @PetroKorienev I did not want to take up too much room explaining what this guy stated perfectly in his analysis. Unfortunately, there is no one-line answer to this (thank Coreplot for that) so it would be very long to scroll through a possible response to this.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer :

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `leftPadding` on the `graph.plotAreaFrame` to leave room for the axis labels at the left side of the graph.

The smeared y-axis is caused by too many tick marks and labels—they overlap and become illegible and negatively impact drawing performance. You need to adjust the labeling parameters to reduce the number of ticks and labels. By default, the axis draws major tick marks and labels one unit apart. The properties that need to be changed depend on the labeling policy you want to use.